# Ways to determine how fast a sequence diverge/converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I have recently read about divergent/convergent sequences, and I wonder what methods are normally used to show how fast a sequence grow. Can I simply find the difference between two adjacent terms? And how can I do this for sequences like harmonic series? 
Thank you!

Here is an example, for a sequence that can be written as an iterated function $$ x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_n^2+1}} $$ How can I determine how fast this series grow?

Comment: You need to first define what you mean by that. There are various definitions of both convergence and divergence rates. Usually you can only compare two sequences

Comment: This is too broad a question. You could perhaps ask to compare the convergence rates two particular sequences. That said, the ratio of terms is more likely to be useful than the difference.

Comment: If your sequence can be seen as the image of a continuous function, then looking at its derivative is a nice way.

Comment: Some people are saying your question is "too broad." Have you looked at any specific sequences?

Comment: If you wish to solve a recurrence relation asymptotically you can sometimes make use of the [Master recurrence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Generic_form) but this only applies to a very specific form. The only thing I can think of for the example you gave is to treat it as a discrete dynamical system and apply qualitative theory, perhaps through examining fixed points. As far as I know there is no general technique for this, non linear difference equations are susceptible to chaos and will nearly never have a closed form.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to Google rate of convergence and asymptotic growth. Many books on numerical analysis also cover this to decide how useful certain algorithms are. A couple of basic ways these are defined are:

Linear convergence $\iff \displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|x_{n+1} - L |}{|x_n - L|} \in (0,1)$

Super-linear and $k$-th order convergence $\iff \displaystyle 0 < \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|x_{n+1} - L |}{|x_n - L|^k} < \infty, \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|x_{n+1} - L |}{|x_n - L|} = 0$

You are interested in the growth rate of the harmonic series, which does not converge (a very elementary proof [here](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/harmonic.pdf)), so there is no $L$ to check speed of convergence as $\infty$ is not allowed here. Assuming by "speed of divergence" you mean the rate of growth (how fast it blows up) there is the famous result that: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} \approx \log n + \gamma, \hspace{2mm} \gamma \approx 0.5772 $$

And so the series grows as fast as the natural logarithm, since we don't really care about constants. This can be proved several ways, one which is a direct application of Euler's summation formula and is on page 480 [here](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf) in Knuth's excellent book, but it is not easy. A more basic way to do this with less accuracy but is good enough for just comparing the growth is using calculus answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905118/finding-big-o-of-the-harmonic-series), the following  [picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence#/media/File:Integral_Test.svg) is useful.

Any function's growth rate can be expressed in "O notation", the simplest is big O, which states that $f(x) \in \mathcal{O}(g(x)) \iff \exists C \in \mathbb{R}_+$ $s.t. |f(x)| \leq C|g(x)|$ $\displaystyle \forall x > x_0 \iff \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < \infty$

For the harmonic series example, if we pretend our approximation is exact, then $|\log n + \gamma | < 2|\log n |$ $\forall x > e^{\gamma}$, and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log(x) + \gamma}{\log(x)} = 1 < \infty$ so $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} \in \mathcal{O}(\log n)$ which quantifies your "rate of divergence" as less than or equal to the logarithm (in fact they are equal, the symbol $\Theta$ is used if $f(x) \in \mathcal{O}(g(x))$ and $g(x) \in \mathcal{O}(f(x))$, try to show the other way round for the example above).